# How to use "On Message" event to check specific message availability over different CAN using Message ID

Tags: logging, can-bus, capl, canoe

I am having measurement log data file offline running in CANoe with more than 15 CANS. I want to check the specific CAN  message availability from different CAN bus while running the offline logfile.
I tried to use “on Message * “event, executing only once as I want to save that result in to text file.
Problem is every time its executing else condition.
Is there any easy solution for the given problem?

Thank you

```
Variable
     dword CANFD_01= 0x1A55549B 
       int MessageExecuted = 0;
     dword readHandle = 0;
     dword readHandle_01 = 0;
      
    
    on start
    {
      setFilePath(path, 1);
      readHandle = openFileWrite("Result.txt",0);
      readHandle_01 = openFileWrite("Result_02.txt",0);
    }
    
    on message *
    {
      
      if(MessageExecuted == 1) return;
      {
      if(this.id == CANFD_01)
          {  
            i = snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer),"CANFD_01 is there  \n");
            filePutString(buffer, elcount(buffer), readHandle);         
          }
       else 
          {
          i = snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer),"CANFD_01s not there with ID: %d\n",this.id);
              filePutString(buffer, elcount(buffer), readHandle_01);
          }
          MessageExecuted = 1; 
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to confirm a specific frame ID across 15 different CAN networks.  Does the following work for you?

```
variables
{
  dword frame_of_interest = 0x1A55549B; /* CANFD_01 */
  dword channel_hits[16];
}
  
on message *
{
  if( 16 > this.can )
  {
    channel_hits[this.can]++;
  }
  else
  {
    write("Channel ID out of range: %d", this.can);
  }
}

on stopMeasurement
{
  byte i;
  
  for(i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    if( 0 < channel_hits[i] )
    {
      write("Channel ID: %d (hits=%d)", i, channel_hits[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you did not use frame_of_interest  in your code..!